# How to remove or avoid advertising ID to transmit for kids app

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ads, policy

I have a kids' stories app targeting 33 Sdk. According to family policy requirements, advertising ID should not be transmitted for kids' apps but admob Sdk has built-in permission for advertising IDs. How to remove these permissions from Sdk.The app is built using Unity.

Q2:How to check advertising Id is not transmitting for app submission

Issueu is attached

I have added this line to the gms manifest file to remove the permission but app is rejected

I can't change the target audience as my store playlisting is directly appealing to children. My app is for under 13 kids.